# Samba file shares - ownership of folder accessible for 1 group verified by MS active direcctory

Tags: network-shares, samba, active-directory, kerberos

I have a machine set up to share a folder `/srv/sambashare`, here's an exerpt of the config file:

```
[share]
   path = /srv/sambashare
   writable = yes
```

The permissions of that folder are set at `700` and it is owned by `nobody:nogroup` at the moment.

The problem I face is probably a simple one but I'm fairly new to Samba so I'm not sure what to do. The contents of the share should be accessible to a particular user who will authenticate with domain credentials, checked against Active Directory by kerberos.

I haven't got kerberos configured yet as I wanted to test the share as soon as samba was configured, albeit basically, to ensure that it works. I've noticed that I can only access & write to the share when the folder is either owned by the user logging in or made world writable.

The key issues are that this folder can't be world writable as it contains sensitive stuff, but at the same time can't be owned by a user or group since they come from the AD server.

Anyone know what I should do?

Comment: This is a fairly broad question as it stands as you don't really have a problem yet - you have a goal and are looking for guidance to reach it. I'd start with a guide, something like: http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory, and then when you have a problem heading down that path, something specific that has a definitive answer, then ask it here.

Comment: On a side note, you need to understand is that *nix and MS do not speak the same language with permissions schemes, so without kerberos installed and configured on *nix, you will not be able to do basic tests of functionality as you are missing a fundamental piece.

Comment: Yeah... I think I'm pre-emptively planning for a problem I don't understand and might end up not having....